# AutoHotkey - capture a hotkey combination in one application only - do not prevent other apps from using same combination

Tags: autohotkey

I have created a hotkey that I want to use only in MS Teams (workaround for the lack of 'Reply to message' function).

I assigned it to Ctrl+R, however it seems that it prevents other applications that use the same combination from noticing the hotkey.

The code is below:

```
^r::
if WinActive("ahk_exe Teams.exe")
{
    SoundBeep 200,500
    Send, ^c
    Send, {Tab}
    Send, >
    Sleep, 500
    Send, ^v
    Send, {Enter}
    Send, {Enter}
}
return
```

**Is there a way to tell AHK to let the key combination bubble up when the active app is NOT teams?**
I tried adding an 'else' clause in which I would `Send, ^r` but that didn't work.

Comment: If you want a nice implementation of Microsoft Teams Smart Reply feature see the code here: https://github.com/tdalon/ahk/blob/master/Lib/Teams.ahk Demo is available here: https://tdalon.blogspot.com/2020/11/teams-shortcuts-smart-reply.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I got it. Posting the working solution.

It seems I needed to wrap the hotkey declaration within the [#ifwinactive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) directive.

```
#IfWinActive("ahk_exe Teams.exe")
^r::
    SoundBeep 200,500
    Send, ^c
    Send, {Tab}
    Send, >
    Sleep, 500
    Send, ^v
    Send, {Enter}
    Send, {Enter}
return
#IfWinActive
```

An even better, comprehensive solution and more powerful approach by @ThierryDalon - https://github.com/tdalon/ahk/blob/master/Lib/Teams.ahk
https://tdalon.blogspot.com/2020/11/teams-shortcuts-smart-reply.html

Comment: Don't use `#If` unless you actually need to. `#IfWinActive` should be used here: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm `#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Teams.exe`

Comment: See comment above. You shall rather use #IfWinActive instead. I have posted the proper answer to your question

Comment: @ThierryDalon - thanks, but that was quite needless - a comment was fine, an edit would be even better, whereas an answer with such minor change is redundant.

Comment: sorry I didn't know I could have edited your post. but though I would have expected you accept the better answer. now others won't see the learning here

Comment: @ThierryDalon -  That's fine, no worries - I have incorporated the change you suggested. Also, thanks for the link, it looks great.